# Item Alignment in Navbar

Tags: html, css

I am utilizing w3schools' HTML5 and CSS to re-design our organization's public website. I currently have a logo in the center with I would like to have the bottom aligned with the bottom of the gray navbar. I also am having an issue displaying the font awesome 5 menu bars when the site is displayed in responsive mode (smaller than 1000px wide). I am not sure which CSS rules to apply to make this all work...

[JSFiddle Initial](https://jsfiddle.net/KhmerBoi1/3wq5ebop/)

***UPDATE 1***

I was able to produce what I would like by adding a height to the col with the logos in it and setting positioning on the large logo. If there is a better way to do this please advise.

No, I just need help getting the bars to show up when the screen size is smaller than 1000px.

[JSFiddle with Update 1](https://jsfiddle.net/KhmerBoi1/vquagfh1/2/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gugi|Lato|Raleway|Roboto|Roboto+Condensed">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css">
<style>
    body {
        /* font-family: 'Gugi', cursive; */
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        /* font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; */
        /* font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; */
        /* font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; */
        /* font-family: palatino, helvetica, sans-serif; */
        /* font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, sans-serif; */
        background: #C6CCD0!important;
    }

    .w3-content {
        max-width: 1200px;
    }

    #banner {
        background-color: #022a3a;
    }

    ul.breadcrumb {
        padding: 2.5px 4px;
        list-style: none;
        background-color: transparent;
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 0.85;
    }

    ul.breadcrumb li {
        display: inline;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    ul.breadcrumb li+li::before {
        padding: 4px;
        color: #fffef9;
        /* content: "/\00a0"; */
        content: ">";
    }

    ul.breadcrumb li a {
        color: #fffef9;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    ul.breadcrumb li a:hover {
        color: #e8b00f;
        font-weight: 900;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    ul.social {
        padding: 5px 8px;
        list-style: none;
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    ul.social li {
        color: #fffef9;
        display: inline;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    ul.social li+li::before {
        padding: 4px;
        color: #fffef9;
        /* content: "/\00a0"; */
    }

    ul.social li a {
        color: #fffef9;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    ul.social li a:hover {
        color: #e8b00f;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #logo {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0 0 25px;
    }

    .gbl-logo {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 78px;
        width: 180px;
        outline: none;
        background: transparent url("http://www.navy.mil/imgs/americas-navy-globe.png") no-repeat 0 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        /* text-indent: -9000px; */
        text-indent: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #___gcse_0 {
        float: right;
        width: 75%;
    }

    .gsc-control-cse {
        /* font-family: Arial, sans-serif; */
        border-color: #022a3a!important;
        background-color: #022a3a!important;
    }

    .gsc-search-button-v2,
    .gsc-search-button-v2:focus {
        border-color: #C6CCD0!important;
        background-color: #0076a9!important;
        background-image: none;
        filter: none;
    }

    .gsc-search-button-v2:hover {
        border-color: #C6CCD0!important;
        background-color: #e8b00f!important;
        background-image: none;
        filter: none;
    }

    #navbar {
        height: 38.5px;
    }

    .loc-logo {
        width: 100px;
        /* height: 125px; */
        /* position: absolute; */
        /* bottom: 0; */
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <!-- Start Banner and Navbar -->
    <div class="w3-top">
        <div id="banner" class="w3-hide-small w3-hide-medium">
            <div class="w3-content">
                <div class="w3-row">
                    <div class="w3-col m8 l9">
                        <!-- Start Sit Collection Breadcrumbs -->
                        <ul class="breadcrumb">
                            <li><a href="#">Commander, Naval Surface Force, U.S. Pacific Fleet (COMNAVSURFPAC)</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Commander, Naval Surface Group, Western Pacific (COMNAVSURFGRUWP)</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Commander, Amphibious Squadron ELEVEN (COMPHIBRON 11)</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">USS Ashland (LSD 48)</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- End Sit Collection Breadcrumbs -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3-col m4 l3">
                        <!-- Start Social Media Links -->
                        <ul class="social">
                            <li>Follow Us On:</li>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Follow Us On Facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Follow Us On Twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Follow Us On Flickr"><i class="fab fa-flickr"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Follow Us On Wordpress"><i class="fab fa-wordpress"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Follow Us On Youtube"><i class="fab fa-youtube-square"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- End Social Media Links -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="w3-row">
                    <!-- Start Site Logo -->
                    <h1 id="logo">
                        <a class="gbl-logo" href="#" title="Commander, Naval Surface Force, U.S. Pacific Home Page">
                            <span>Commander, Naval Surface Force, U.S. Pacific Home Page</span>
                        </a>
                    </h1>
                    <!-- Start Site Logo -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-content">
            <div id="navbar" class="w3-bar">
                <div class="w3-row">
                    <div class="w3-col l5">
                        <!-- Start Global (Left) Navbar -->
                        <div class="w3-left w3-hide-small w3-hide-medium">
                            <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
                            <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
                            <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
                            <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
                            <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Global (Left) Navbar -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3-col l2 s3 m6">
                        <a class="w3-hide-large w3-left" href="#home">
                            <img style="width: 30px; margin: 0 10px; display: block;" src="https://www.public.navy.mil/surfor/crests/ashland_med.gif" />
                        </a>
                        <a class="w3-hide-small w3-hide-medium" href="#home">
                            <img style="width: 100px; margin: 0 auto; display: block;" src="https://www.public.navy.mil/surfor/crests/ashland_med.gif" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3-col l5">
                        <!-- Start Local (Right) Navbar -->
                        <div class="w3-right w3-hide-small w3-hide-medium">
                            <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
                            <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
                            <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
                            <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
                            <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Local (Right) Navbar -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3-col s1 m3">
                        <!-- Hide Navbars and Display Menu Icon -->
                        <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-right w3-hide-large" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_open()">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't confuse the W3.org with w3schools.com. Apples and beavers

Comment: if you leave in the style in the heading (and remove the w3.css , which seems to be completely overriding it), the look of the code looks very different.Also , please try and format your fiddles correctly in future. Links can be added on the left hand side, css pane is to the right . https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/60voLqm9/

Comment: @RachelGallen I updated you JSFiddle to include the w3.CSS. The Formatting now looks correct. And the above issues still are in question. https://jsfiddle.net/vquagfh1/

Comment: @TroyPilewski you seem to have missed the point. Removing the w3.css improved the code and corrected some errors. Have another look and maybe you will progress.

Comment: @RachelGallen Removing the w3.css removes the use of the responsive classes. I only used to CSS in the header to overide specific things I need changed to diviate from the w3. Without the W3CSS you see two icon in the center when you should only see one. One is for the large screens and the other is for small and medium screens.

Comment: @TroyPilewski Learn about media queries so you can understand and manipulate them (instead of copying and pasting)

Comment: @RachelGallen Thank you for the constructive criticism. I will take you advice.

Comment: @TroyPilewski Good on you. It's worth it. Easier  the long term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically your `fa bars` icon is rendering properly, but it is pushed down to the next line, outside of the navbar bounds.

[image]

---

To fix this, I did a couple things.  First I moved all the `hide-medium`, `hide-small` and `hide-large` classes up to the column level.  This keeps the entire column from rendering even when the content inside them is hidden.  Second I moved the large icon and small icon into their own columns (again, so now we can hide the entire column instead of just part of it).  Then I adjusted the column size for the small icon.  All this allowed the menu icon to be rendered inside the bounds of the navbar.

https://jsfiddle.net/vquagfh1/27/

[image]

```
<div id="navbar" class="w3-bar">
    <div class="w3-row">
      <div class="w3-col l5">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="w3-col l1 s1 m1 w3-hide-large" style="height: 38.5px;">
        ...
      </div>        
      <div class="w3-col l2 s3 m6 w3-hide-small w3-hide-medium" style="height: 38.5px;">
        ...
      </div>       
      <div class="w3-col s1 m1 w3-hide-large">
        <!-- Hide Navbars and Display Menu Icon -->
        <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-right" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_open()">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-col l5 w3-hide-small w3-hide-medium">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I want the navbars to be hidden when the screen size is less that 1000px. My next thing will be to have a sidebar menu pop out. The fa fa-bars does not show up when less than 1000px. I'm trying to work through this in pieces.

Comment: In your question you say "I just need help getting the bars to **show up** when screen size is smaller than 1000px."  So do you want the bars VISIBLE or HIDDEN under 1000px?

Comment: The fa-bars not the navbars

Comment: I see what you want now. Hold on.

Comment: The height is suppose to be set at a specific amount as well

Comment: Updated. It has a couple issues, but I think the basic goal is accomplished. Check it out and let me know if you have questions. (admittedly though, I'm not fully comfortable with this w3 library)

Comment: Basically think of your rows and columns as your "building blocks" and apply the `hide` classes to them as needed.

Comment: I implemented your changes and all seems to be working great! Thank you!